# Invalid scenario

Tags: uml

Are we suppose to describe such scenario:

Lets suppose that we have a fnc:

```
void delete(int value);
```

And now, am I suppose to describe scenario when user supplies value of type not convertible to int? It won't even compile, so what's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see how this is about uml modeling, but anyway: the reason for this would be to show that if a value comes from somewhere not inside the compiled code (say a web page, a different application or something), the function will either not work, delete the wrong thing or return an error, depending on what is preferrable.

If this truly is about uml and modeling an application, the point of this exercise would probably be to show that you have given such a scenario thought and have a certain degree of control and error handling in your solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As to answer to your question and clarify why this is a UML modeling I can say that as a walk through (which is a part and form of UML modelling) you should provide regular, alternative and invalid scenario.